# Dense orbit in real linear fractional transformation

Tags: dynamical-systems, linear-fractional-transformation

Consider $f:\mathbb{R} \backslash \{-2\}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+2}$. Is there a real number that the orbit $\{f(r), f\circ f(r), \cdots\}$is dense in some interval? If there is, can you classify them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identically we have $f^7=f$, hence all orbits are finite.